# Cannot convert Hebrew characters using pdftotext

Tags: character-encoding, hebrew, pdftotext

I have a PDF file that I can see and open, and send to every one:

[image: The PDF I can read and see clearly]

Now I want to convert it to text. I am using Linux so I use these 3 commands:

1. `pdftotext -enc ISO-8859-8 -layout barIlan.pdf bar.txt`
2. `pdftotext -enc UTF-8 -layout barIlan.pdf bar.txt`
3. `pdftotext -layout barIlan.pdf bar.txt`

Each command did convert the PDF to text, but when I open the converted file I see:

[image: The text after I convert it]

I tried all the commands to convert it to text with a different encoding, but that did not help.

I am pretty sure it is a problem with the encoding because I have another Hebrew PDF, and when I use the command `pdftotext -layout Ariel.pdf ariel.txt` it works, and shows me the Hebrew characters.